# Increasing quota limit for CPUs for All Region

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I just created a GCP account and I am trying to increase the limit of Compute Engine API Quota for `CPUs (all regions)` to more than 12.

It says that I need to contact their sales team. I did and I got a confirmation of successful quota increase saying that my quota will be updated in an hour. It has been a week and when I look at my CPUs limit, it is still 12.

[image]

I tried the process multiple times, but I can't get the limit up.

I am starting to think that the increase in quota that I am requesting and the one that I am looking at is not the same.

I tried to contact their sales based on the instruction. I was able to successfully follow the automated process. I even got a successful response saying that the increased quota should be available. But, after 7 days, the limit remains the same.

Comment: From the email you received, what is the exact wording on which quota was increased? From my experience, it is unusual that Google will increase the quota for a **new** account. From your screenshot, you are not using any of your CPU quota. Usually, you must justify a quota increase and you are using 0.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did just sent me a generic email like this:

`Dear Developer,
We have approved your request for additional quota. Your new quota should take effect within one hour of receiving this message.`

Comment: The only task you can do is request a quota increase again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/resource-usage#resource_usage_quotas), Not all projects have the same quotas. As you increasingly use Google Cloud over time, your quotas might increase accordingly. If you expect a notable upcoming increase in usage, you can proactively request quota adjustments from the [Quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?_ga=2.188520683.2110638510.1687755575-915200868.1685529292) page in the Google Cloud console.

As John Hanley said, you need to use the current allocated usage then only you can request for Quota. So, use that 12 CPU limit shown in screenshot then request for quota and also you need to show the billing account has additional history to request the quota.

**Can you check on below points for more information or clarity :**

> - If your project's billing service is disrupted or if you change your project's billing account, your quotas reset to their default
>   values.
> - To view your quotas, you must have the `serviceusage.quotas.get`    permission.
> - To change your quotas, you must have the `serviceusage.quotas.update` permission.

- Keep in touch with the [Google Sales Team](https://cloud.google.com/contact) for further assistance.
- Refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/resource-usage#cpu_quota) for CPU Usage Quota.

***Note:*** Quota limits are updated once per day. As you have mentioned you got a confirmation a week ago but note that the changes to limits can take up to 24 hours only to be updated in the Google Cloud console. If Google mentioned that the quota increased then it will reflect in your console.You can also raise an issue request [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).